# trying to configure mysql-innodb-cluster but have Pods pending error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, mysql-cluster, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am trying to configure mysql-innodb-cluster using helm.

Here is command : `helm install mycluster mysql-operator/mysql-innodbcluster -n mysql-cluster`.

I already have made rook-ceph storageclass.

But pods are still pending.

I really don't know how to solve that problems

First, I checked description of pvc, pod and svc.

Second, I tryed to change the vaules in the helm chart

Here is value.yaml

```yaml
image:
pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
pullSecrets:
enabled: false
secretName:
credentials:
root:
user: root

# password: sakila

    host: "%"

tls:
useSelfSigned: false

# caSecretName:

# serverCertAndPKsecretName:

# routerCertAndPKsecretName: # our use router.certAndPKsecretName

\#serverVersion: 8.0.31
serverInstances: 3
routerInstances: 1 # or use router.instances
baseServerId: 1000

\#router:

# instances: 1

# certAndPKsecretName:

# podSpec:

# podAnnotations:

# podLabels:

\#keyring:

# file:

# fileName:

# readOnly:

# storage:

# encryptedFile:

# fileName:

# readOnly:

# storage:

# password:

# oci:

# user: "ocid1.user.oc1..."

# keySecret: "oci-credentials"

# keyFingerprint: ""

# tenancy: "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..."

# compartment: "ocid1.compartment.oc1..."

# virtualVault: "ocid1.vault.oc1.."

# masterKey: "ocid1.key.oc1..."

# caCertificate: ""

# endpoints:

# encryption: "\<identifier\>-crypto.kms.\<region\>.oraclecloud.com"

# management: "\<identifier\>-management.kms.\<region\>.oraclecloud.com"

# vaults: "vaults.\<region\>.oci.oraclecloud.com"

# secrets: "secrets.vaults.\<region\>.oci.oraclecloud.com"

\#podSpec:

# containers:

# - name: mysql

# resources:

# requests:

# memory: "2048Mi"  # adapt to your needs

# cpu: "1800m"      # adapt to your needs

# limits:

# memory: "8192Mi"  # adapt to your needs

# cpu: "3600m"      # adapt to your needs

# 

\#podAnnotations:
\#podLabels:

\#serverConfig:

# mycnf: |

# \[mysqld\]

# core_file

# local_infile=off

\#datadirVolumeClaimTemplate:

# accessModes:

# resources:

# requests:

# storage:

\#initDB:

# dump:

# name:

# path:

# options:

# includeSchemas:

# ociObjectStorage:

# prefix:

# bucketName:

# credentials:

# persistentVolumeClaim:

# clone:

# donorUrl:

# rootUser:

# credentials:

\#backupProfiles:
\#- name: dump-instance-profile-pvc

# dumpInstance:

# dumpOptions:

# excludeSchemas: \["excludeme"\]

# storage:

# persistentVolumeClaim:

# claimName: backup-volume-claim-1

\#- name: dump-instance-profile-oci

# dumpInstance:

# dumpOptions:

# excludeSchemas: \["excludeme"\]

# storage:

# ociObjectStorage:

# prefix : /

# bucketName: idbcluster_backup

# credentials: oci-credentials

# 

\#- name: snapshot-profile-oci

# snapshot:

# storage:

# ociObjectStorage:

# prefix : /

# bucketName: idbcluster_backup

# credentials: oci-credentials

\#backupSchedules:
\#- name: schedule-ref

# schedule: "\*/1 \* \* \* \*"

# deleteBackupData: false

# backupProfileName: dump-instance-profile-oci

# enabled: true

\#- name: schedule-inline

# schedule: "\*/1 \* \* \* \*"

# deleteBackupData: false

# enabled: true

# backupProfile:

# dumpInstance:

# dumpOptions:

# excludeSchemas: \["excludeme"\]

# storage:

# ociObjectStorage:

# prefix : /

# bucketName: idbcluster_backup

# credentials: oci-credentials
```

I write storage classs in the datadirVolumeClaimTemplate sector like this :

```yaml
datadirVolumeClaimTemplate:
accessModes: \["ReadWriteOnce"\]
resources:
storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
requests:
storage: "10Gi"
```

And I reinstall this helm chart but I can't still solve this probems and configure mysql innodb cluster.